# Municipal websites with air pollution information

Tags: air-pollution, open-data

I am looking for ways to present real-time meteorological and pollutant data in a website. Searching the internet for pollutant data, I've found interesting sites for [Dublin](https://dublincityairandnoise.ie/), [Thermi](https://app.thermiair.gr/dashboard) (in Greece), and [London](https://www.airqualityengland.co.uk/local-authority/?la_id=86) (if I understand correctly, the measurements from all of England are actually presented)

Finding those, I would like to ask if you know of any other sites from municipalities that present real time data about air pollution and meteorological parameters. (If you have data from states or country, I would like to know, but I would prefer it from municipalities)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking for.  Are you looking for other cities that have similar sites to what you have linked?  Or something different?

Comment: @f.thorpe Yes, I am looking for other cities that have other similar sites. Thanks.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest hello, I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for different ways data can be displayed, which shows current meteorology and air quality information.  But the sites you link to look like just air quality sites.  Sites that show both are rare, but some USA sites that do it include https://enviwa.ecology.wa.gov/home/map and https://www.airnowtech.org/navigator/  AirnowTech Navigator is especially impressive because it's pulling in meteorology from the weather station network, not just weather data from the air quality sites.

Comment: In this case do not know sites displaying either of them? Thanks.

Comment: The first site you provided is very helpful, it can't login in the second one since I do not belong in any of the agencies, but in any case thanks about these two. But in any case thanks. (@f.thorpe)

Comment: OK I wasn't sure if that was useful for you, I've listed some more in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with air quality monitoring website maps in Europe, but in the USA there are many of them.  However, most only show pollutants being monitored, and do not include meteorology.  There are some that include both, since many air quality monitor stations also include some meteorological instrumentation.  Here are a few examples of sites that include both:

- [California](https://www.arb.ca.gov/aqmis2/map_pages/gmap.php)
- [Nevada](https://desaqmonitoring.clarkcountynv.gov/)
- [Oregon](https://aqi.oregon.gov/)
- [Texas](https://tceq.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=ab6f85198bda483a997a6956a8486539)
- [Washington](https://enviwa.ecology.wa.gov/home/map)
- [New Jersey](https://njdep.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=76194937cbbe46b1ab9a9ec37c7d709b)

[AirNow Tech Navigator](https://www.airnowtech.org/index.cfm?page=login) is the best site, since it pulls in weather data from the National Weather Service as well as satellite data and other sources of information that you can plot alongside the air quality data.  It also allows you to do HYSPLIT trajectories and wind roses on the fly.  However, it requires that you are a member of an agency, company, or university on their list in order to get an account.  Below is an example of the type of map plot you can make with the tool, from [here](https://apps.ecology.wa.gov/publications/documents/1902004.pdf).  Though, the site doesn't show "current" air quality.  Instead it lets you pick the date/time to within a few hours of current (or maybe "yesterday").

[image]
*24-hour HYSPLIT back trajectories at 50 (green), 500 (blue), and 2000 (red) meter starting heights on September 6, 2017 for Yakima. Four back trajectories are shown starting at 4 am, 10 am, 4 pm, and 10 pm PST. HMS-detected hot-spots are shown as red triangles. The background layer is Aqua/MODIS imagery (~2 pm LT). The wind barbs and hourly PM2.5 shown are monitored values at 2 PM PST.*

Comment: Just a heads up, can do HYSPLIT at https://www.ready.noaa.gov/hypub-bin/trajsrc.pl, or are you saying something more advanced?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest hello, no I am interested in sites implemented by municipalities or states. I am interestined in the way the present the data/plot/maps.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest there are many places to do HYSPLIT, and you can download it too.  But the AirNow Tech Navigator site allows you to do HYSPLIT on-the-fly overlayed on the satellite imagery map with air monitors, NWS wind barbs, etc, etc.  So, if you are looking to make advanced plots quickly it is much better.  I've added an image and example link in the answer.